# Ignore specific URL in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a standard set of WordPress rewrites in my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But I want to avoid any rewriting on a specific URL, which is:

```
http://www.domain.com/wp-content/themes/jarvis_wp/css/i?w=400&amp;h=250
```

I tried adding this rule ABOVE the WordPress rewrites:

```
RewriteRule ^css - [L,NC]
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. How can I let that URL be loaded by the browser without any rewriting whatsoever?

This is the code in the index.php file which is inside the "i" folder, perhaps this may have something to do with the redirect, I'm not sure where its coming from:

```
<?php
// Include placeholder generator class
require('placeholder.class.php');

// Get variables from $_GET
$width           = isset($_GET['w']) ? trim($_GET['w']) : null;
$height          = isset($_GET['h']) ? trim($_GET['h']) : null;
$backgroundColor = isset($_GET['bgColor']) ? strtolower(trim($_GET['bgColor'])) : null;
$textColor       = isset($_GET['textColor']) ? strtolower(trim($_GET['textColor'])) : null;
$cache           = isset($_GET['c']) && $_GET['c'] == 1 ? true : false;

try {
    $placeholder = new Placeholder();
    $placeholder->setWidth($width);
    $placeholder->setHeight($height);
    $placeholder->setCache($cache);
    if ($backgroundColor) $placeholder->setBackgroundColor($backgroundColor);
    if ($textColor) $placeholder->setTextColor($textColor);
    $placeholder->render();
} catch (Exception $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
RewriteRule ^css - [L,NC]
```

try

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/themes/jarvis_wp/css/i - [L]
```

Comment: Hmm, neither of these suggestions are working in this case. I'm wondering if the redirect is not happening at the .htaccess level. I'm going to post the contents of the "i" folder's index.php file in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell it to ignore the wp-content folder so it doesn't do a rewrite.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: See same comment below.

Comment: Where is the location of your htaccess file?

Comment: Root directory of site.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache or try in another browser. The rule should work.

Comment: I've done that, still not working. Either I have something wrong here, or the redirect isn't happening via .htaccess. I could post the real URL here, but I don't think Stack Overflow likes that kind of thing.